# Oracle find customers who haven't rented in the past 3 years

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a database, with a few tables. One of them is a customer table, one of them is a rental table, and one of them is a rental details table. Let's call them `C`, `R` and `RD` respectively. `RD` has the `date_in` and `date_out` of the tools rented, and is linked to `R` by `RD`'s primary key. `R` is linked to `C` by `customer id`.

Basically what I want to do is select (and delete) customers that have not rented anything in the past 3 years. So I can't use where `date_out > sysdate - 3 years` [representation not accurate code] because the tool might have been rented out 4 years ago and ALSO last week, so it needs to be kept in the database... I just need to delete tools that haven't been rented at all in the past 3 years.

I know the database structure is retarded but I can't change it.

Comment: Logically the only way to do this is to check for every customer, the last tool they rented, then the date in/out of that tool. This would be quite long winded. Another solution would be to add 'last rental date' to the customer table, would change the structure, only add more to it. You could then query one table to see if customers have been inactive for three years.

Comment: do you want to delete customers or tools?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
delete from c 
where not exists ( select * 
                   from r join rd using(r_id) 
                   where c_id=c.c_id and date_out>add_months(sysdate,-36) )
```

Comment: Like I said on the other answer, these look really good, just might work... when I get to work tomorrow I will test it out and let you know how it goes. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: But, what exactly is `c.id` do you mean `c.c_id`?

Comment: c.is is the id from table c—you didn't say in the question what it is called, so I'm making an assumption: is it named `c_id`?

Comment: It's always useful to give minimal working `create table` statements in the question itself btw

Comment: Oh right, primary key of customer table is customer_id let's call it c_id just for now, so when you say `where c_id=c.id and date_out>add_months(sysdate,-36)` you mean join c_id from R with c_id for C as the common column? Righto.

Comment: Oh, I'm very sorry, I would have normally posted the create statements with even an ERM, but we're having some complications here and I just wanted an idea... next time I will write one up.

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't use the word "join" in this context. `c.c_id` refers to `c_id` of table `c` in the outer query, yes.

Comment: Right, many thanks, I'll get to it ASAP and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your schema correctly, you should be able to write something like this:

```
DELETE
  FROM c
 WHERE c_id NOT IN
        ( SELECT DISTINCT c_id
            FROM r
           WHERE r_id IN
                  ( SELECT r_id
                      FROM rd
                     WHERE date_out > SYSDATE - (365 * 3 + 1)
                  )
        )
;
```

to delete all `c` records that have no corresponding `r` records with `rd` records in the past three years. (For "three years" I used 365 × 3 + 1 days, which is hackish but IMHO simple and straightforward. You can improve this if you want.)

Note that the above will only work properly if your foreign keys have `ON DELETE CASCADE`; if not, then you'll need to start by deleting the `r` and `rd` records associated with these customers. For that, you can use the same approach as the above query.

Comment: `not exists` is *usually* preferable to `not in`

Comment: This looks brilliant... and reply was fast as lightning... I thought I'd only get a reply tomorrow so I've kind of packed up here, but I will check this as soon as I get in tomorrow, but this may just work. Thanks very much.

Comment: @JackDouglas: Can you elaborate on that? "Preferable" in what way? Do you have any helpful links? (Thanks in advance!)

Comment: @JackDouglas: Thanks. I disagree with your assessment, but it's good to know that there are people who hold that view. :-)

Comment: @JackDouglas: Re: `null` in `t2`: Obviously a broken schema will give broken results. That's not a reason to write your queries differently when you do have a correct schema. Re: timings and plans: I just ran your non-null fiddle a bunch of times (with and without primary keys), and the timings were usually identical. Sometimes one would suddenly take much longer, but when that happened I found that it was more often the `NOT EXISTS` that took a long time, which hardly supports your point!

Comment: @JackDouglas: Look, I'm not a noob. I've written, and performance-tuned, a lot of complex queries on very large Oracle tables. You seem to settled on the rule of thumb that a correlated `NOT EXISTS` is always better than an uncorrelated `NOT IN`, and I have no wish to disabuse you of that rule of thumb. It doesn't seem harmful. But I find that an uncorrelated `NOT IN` is usually clearer, often easier to work with, and (despite what you imply) occasionally significantly faster, so I'm not inclined to adopt your rule of thumb without a more compelling reason.